Отправка письма на почту из qt

Хочу реализовать двухфакторную аутентификацию на qt c++, каким образом можно отправить сгенерированный пароль на почту?
Пишу под линукс и cmake
Буду очень благодарен за наглядные примеры.

гугл в помощь: https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt
